# Making repeating code shorter

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

How can I make this code shorter? For example with a foreach.

```
    if($Email == NULL){
        $Email = "-";
    }
    elseif($Age == NULL){
        $Age = "-";
    }
    elseif($Sex == NULL){
        $Sex = "-";
    }
```

It has to be replaced with like this

```
$search = array("%UserID%", "%RegDate%", "%Name%", "%Email%", "%Age%", "%Gender%");
$replace = array($UserID, $RegDate, $Name, $Email, $Age, $Sex);
$content = str_replace($search, $replace, $content);
```

**Edit:**

I've got it like this now is it possible to use the $variable = $row in the ternary code too? Btw I have a variables.php file where I use ternary code to define and I already tried it there but because it was being used earlier it didnt work and I didnt think of it :P

But this current code works I just wonder if it can be shorter.

```
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($accountinforesult)){
    $UserID = $row['UserID'];
    $RegDate = $row['RegDate'];
    $Name = $row['Name'];
    $Email = $row['Email'];
    $Age = $row['Age'];
    $Sex = $row['Sex'];

    $UserID = isset($UserID) ? $UserID : "-";
    $RegDate = isset($RegDate) ? $RegDate : "-";
    $Name = isset($Name) ? $Name : "-";
    $Email = isset($Email) ? $Email : "-";
    $Age = isset($Age) ? $Age : "-";
    $Sex = isset($Sex) ? $Sex : "-";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but I believe this should work.

```
$vars = array('UserID', 'RegDate', 'Name', 'Email', 'Age', 'Sex');
foreach ($vars as $k => $v) {
    $$v = ($$v !== NULL) ? $$v : '-';
}
```

$$v means "the variable with name $v". If $v = 'foo' then $$v is $foo.

Look at "variable variables": http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: This one works too thank you thats really usefull and looks good!

Comment: Excellent solution, Pedro! Not one I would have thought of.

Comment: IMHO this is a solution I would highly recommend to avoid! Dynamic variables are a very bad solution for any problem.

Comment: @fdomig Normally I would agree, but not in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Email = is_null($Email) ? "-" : $Email;
```

You figure the rest

Answer (score 0):

I've got it like this now is it possible to use the $variable = $row in the ternary code too?
Btw I have a variables.php file where I use ternary code to define and I already tried it there but because it was being used earlier it didnt work and I didnt think of it :P

But this current code works I just wonder if it can be shorter.

```
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($accountinforesult)){
    $UserID = $row['UserID'];
    $RegDate = $row['RegDate'];
    $Name = $row['Name'];
    $Email = $row['Email'];
    $Age = $row['Age'];
    $Sex = $row['Sex'];

    $UserID = isset($UserID) ? $UserID : "-";
    $RegDate = isset($RegDate) ? $RegDate : "-";
    $Name = isset($Name) ? $Name : "-";
    $Email = isset($Email) ? $Email : "-";
    $Age = isset($Age) ? $Age : "-";
    $Sex = isset($Sex) ? $Sex : "-";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = array(
  'Email' => $Email,
  'Age' => $Age,
  'Gender' => $Sex,
);

foreach($params as $paramName => $paramValue) {
  $paramValue = is_null($paramValue) ? '-' : $paramValue;
  //$paramValue = mysql_real_escape_string($paramValue); // or something like that...
  $content = str_replace('%'.$paramName.'%', $paramValue, $content);
}
```